# Apply two scripts to a spreadsheet that has multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I was able to find script that work for each sheet in a separate file, but can I have 2 scripts applied to a single file, but 2 sheets respectively? Essentially what I am after is this:

I am a pilot and I keep track of my logbook and flight times in a Google Sheets file. I have used this means for years but recently tried to apply some scripts to get to the first empty cell in column A as that is where I start with the date for each entry. The main reason for this is my sheet is now in excess of 3000 rows of entries. The first sheet in my file where I record my flights is titled "LOGBOOK". I have found a script to apply `onOpen` that will place my cursor to the first empty row of column A each time I open. Below is the script that I use. It works but takes approx 10 seconds to complete. If there is a faster means, I am open to suggestions. I only want to know the first empty cell in column A. This is what I use currently:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var maxIndex = values.reduce(function(maxIndex, row, index) {
    return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
  }, 0);
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1));
}
```

[Screen shot of Sheet 1, "LOGBOOK"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Ar4.png)

The second sheet in this file is titled "FLIGHT DUTY" In this sheet I want the same function to happen onOpen. I want the cursor to be placed in the first empty cell of column A as well. Again, I start column A with a date input for the given flight duty period. If I break this sheet out to a stand along Google Sheets file, this script works:

```
function onOpen(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Find the last cell with data in that specific column (A in this case)
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
  //Activate the next cell
  lastCell.offset(1, 0).activate();
}
```

[Screen shot of sheet 2 "Flight Duty"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qukoQ.png)

In my current Google Sheets file, I want Sheet 1 "LOGBOOK" to `onOpen`, place my cursor to the first empty cell in Column A. At the same time, onOpen, I want Sheet 2 "FLIGHT DUTY" to place my cursor in the first empty cell of Column A of that sheet when I select that tab.

Below is a screen shot of the SHEET names at the bottom. The only sheets that I need a script for are 1 LOGBOOK and 2 FLIGHT DUTY.

[Screen shot of Sheet Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB965.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more stable version

```
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('↓ Go to ... ↓')
    .addItem('first empty row', 'goToFirstEmptyRow')
    .addToUi();
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange('A'+getFirstEmptyDataRow(sh)).offset(1,0).activate();
}
function goToFirstEmptyRow(event){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sh.getRange('A'+getFirstEmptyDataRow(sh)).offset(1,0).activate();
}
function getFirstEmptyDataRow(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4");
  return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();           
}
```

You have a menu at the top right
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
function onOpen(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange('A'+getFirstEmptyDataRow(sh)).offset(1,0).activate();
}
function onSelectionChange(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange('A'+getFirstEmptyDataRow(sh)).offset(1,0).activate();
}
function getFirstEmptyDataRow(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4");
  return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();           
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Um9gnfz3VH6Vf0PwNVW8LOD3F63qb5h7PQl-hSYT_0E/copy

Comment: Thanks for this. Noted on the proper use of case sensitivity when naming sheets. I have added your recommended script but when I select the FLIGHT DUTY tab, cursor remains in A1. By selection change, is it simply just clicking on Sheet 2 name at the bottom? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer, feel free to criticize

Comment: Ok so to follow up, I now see a note within your script //here your script. I think that is a note anyway. Sorry, I am totally new to all of this. Am I supposed to add more script here in this place? I have only gotten lucky searching this forum and finding examples how to get to the first empty cell in a column. I have no idea how to create my own script. If you have time, would you be so kind to complete the script so I could copy and paste? Many thanks, and sorry if my questions are basic but I have zero scripting experience.

Comment: When I copy and paste the new script, upon RUN I get this:  Execution log
9:16:09 AM Notice Execution started
9:16:09 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onOpen @ Code.gs:2

Comment: take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Um9gnfz3VH6Vf0PwNVW8LOD3F63qb5h7PQl-hSYT_0E/copy

Comment: Thank you Mike for your continued troubleshooting. I took a copy and tried to run the script. It prompted me to allow my Google Account to be accessed and when I run I get this: Execution log
12:00:04 PM Notice Execution started
12:00:05 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onOpen @ Code.gs:2

Comment: I should also point out, I am not looking for last row +1, I want first empty cell in column A. My sheet is now 3000+ lines long and once a month or so I add extra rows as needed to allow for the upcoming months entries. The bottom couple rows have a border and notes for the logbook.  See simplified copy with just a few rows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3R6kqC3YSw7ydjsYAkn-wckzNQecbyFwPjeDvut0M0/edit?usp=sharing On sheet one I would like my cursor to end up at A8 and sheet 2, A46 based on entries to date.

Comment: I updated the script which allows you to go to the first empty line. However, in your spreadsheet you will need to replace A1 with A4 because some cells contain IGNORE! The second problem is that you will never change anything other than the selected cell. I'm trying to implement a flag but it inhibits the script! It's why, I think, we could better add a menu to do that.

Comment: See my other answer!

Comment: Thanks so much Mike. I quite like this menu idea as I can run it on sheet 1 and sheet 2 as needed. Many thanks. Yeah I put ignore in at A4 which would have been blank otherwise. This allowed my script to skip past that and actually take be down to the first empty cell I was after. Many thanks. I will paste this into my master sheet now which is much much longer and see how it behaves. Many thanks... Merci

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This was my first time using onselectionchange and the behavior is a bit weird. I also think the menu is much more useful.

Comment: It works very well. I know I can rename the menu button. For example, I changed in from "first empty row" to "New Entry". Is there a means to not have to hit the menu of "Go TO" and then choose "New Entry"? I mean since that is all I will ever do, is it possible to have "New Entry" on the top tool bar and single click for that 'gotofirstemptyrow' without the need for a second selection? Not a big deal but just a fine tune so to speak. Thanks again and well done sir.

Comment: No, I don't think so, it's the same for all native menus. If you want to go with a single click, it is possible to put a checkbox somewhere in the sheet and perform an onedit function that will allow you to go to the first empty row. But keep in mind that this checkbox will not be visible at any time if you have passed a certain row so that the cell that contains the checkbox will disappear.

Comment: No this is great as it is. C'est super mon ami! I truly appreciate all of your help. This has made my data entry much more enjoyable. I have never scripted and spent countless hours searching for this. I have stumbled my way around writing formulas and conditional formatting to account for all the variables related to max flight hours and flight duty periods in 1, 7, 28, 90, 365 etc... but scripting was beyond me. Through many trials I got there, but this cleaned it all up. Great stuff and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below code. The last row will be activated in as many sheets as you have. Whichever sheet you open, you will always land at the bottom row. Takes one second to run.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tabs= ss.getSheets();
  for (i=0; i<tabs.length;i++){
    var lr = tabs[i].getLastRow();
    tabs[i].getRange("A"+(lr+1)).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I pasted this exact script into my Google Sheet and it only activated the first empty cell in column A on sheet number 1. Am I supposed to paste it more than one time? Totally new at this. Sheet 2 which is "FLIGHT DUTY", the cursor remains active in A1. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, quick follow up here. I retried this script again, closed all sheets and reopened. What I got was this. Sheet 1 the cursor stayed at cell A1 but for the remaining 7 sheets in this doc, there are 8 in total, the cursor went to the bottom of each sheet + 1 row. I could also see the document jump between sheet tabs as it took place landing on the last sheet, sheet 8, bottom row +1. I only need a script for sheets 1 and 2, "LOGBOOK" and "FLIGHT DUTY" and I want the first empty cell in column A. Not the last row +1 as the last row may sometimes be 20-30 rows below my last LOGBOOK entry. Tks.